# Pandas excel import truncating long string

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

I have an excel file with the below cell content

```
\\pathxx01\xxx project\71 XXXX XXXXXXX Team\Landlord Billing/
```

However, when importing the excel into a pandas dataframe with pd.read_excel method, the string is truncated to

```
\\pathxx01\xxx project\71 XXXX XXXXXXX Team\Lan...
```

Is there any way to avoid this truncation and keep the original string?

Comment: Try `print(df.to_dict())`. Does it appear truncated there?

Comment: No, it does not appear truncated if I do that.

Comment: I doubt that its truncated. It rather prints as truncated because of the small screen space. You should consider extracting that specific value from the dataframe and check whether its truncated

Comment: @Onyambu it is truncated because later on I use the fetched value to deploy a file into that directory, and it is doing it wrong,

Comment: From the answer, it is exactly what I proposed. NO truncation was done. Only for distplay was the string truncated. Otherwise it was stored correctly in the dataframe

Comment: @Onyambu you're partially right. It might be not actually truncated, but when using that parameter to deploy a file in the path, it was not finding the right path, so it was like if it was using the 'truncated' string.

Comment: @banana_99 how can that be the case? You just converted THE SAME to a dictionary, and it worked. The marked answer DID NOT DO ANYTHING to the dataframe but rather just changed the DISPLAY SETTINGS!! Well no need to say much, i perceive you are new to coding and using python/pandas in general

Comment: @Onyambu yes I am, but there error was there and my file was not uploaded to the correct directory because of that truncation, so hence the SO question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As determined from the comments, it's not actually being truncated. Pandas is just displaying it truncated because there is little screenspace where you're displaying it.

You can use this to force Pandas to display the full columns without truncating them:

```py
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
```

Comment: That was actually it, thank you :)

Comment: However, when doing that, it says: FutureWarning: Passing a negative integer is deprecated in version 1.0 and will not be supported in future version. Instead, use None to not limit the column width.
  pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)

Comment: This would be the updated one: pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

Comment: @banana_99 updated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar issues using `xlwings` library, very handy for reasing single cell values to a variable, numpy arrays and pandas dataframes.

A quick sample:

```
import xlwings as xw
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

worksheet = xw.Book(file_path).sheets['Sheet1']
myCellValue= xw.Book(file_path).sheets['Sheet1'].range('M4').value
myArray= np.array(worksheet.range("A1:A100").value)
```

imho this works more solidly than other solutions.